# How to trigger a java function or a class from crontab -e

Tags: java, curl, cron, ftp, fetch

I am trying to run a cronjob every 5 mins, the actual task is to trigger a curl end point
from within the java class in a method.
my crontab -e looks like below:
*/5 * * * * bash /home/ec2-user/script.sh
the above line is working fine but it is not triggering the FTPConnect.start() from the Cron job class
my Cron job looks like below:
@Component
public class CJob{

```
@Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * curl -v http://localhost:8080/apiname/v1/cids/$filename" ) // Every 12 hours
public static void fetchFromSFTP() {
    try {
        FTPConnect.start();
        return;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error running this cron.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what does script.sh look like? And why are you getting both the cron job and the @Scheduled annotation to run at regular intervals?

Comment: java -jar -Daws.AccessKey=<> -Daws.SecretKey=<> -Daws.region=<>Dspring.profiles.active=<> -Dhun-ipt-store=<> -Dhun-ipt-store-pwd=<> -Daws.Secrets=<> -Daws.s3.bucket=<s3bucket path> -Dsftp.filepath=<ftppath> Dsftp.pwd=<>-Dcvs.api.key=<> -Daws.SecretName=<>  -Dcvs.api.channel=<> jarfile-RELEASE.jar  > logfile.log &  :  added crontab-e because @scheduled is not working

Comment: Is your scheduled annotation really defined as `@Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * curl -v http://localhost:8080/apiname/v1/cids/$filename" ) `?.... You can't just add a curl here?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow the way you ask the question and the information you give is pretty confusing - anyways I'm trying to answer.

First of all - as I understood - you have a real `cronjob` activated on a unix machine, which is executing a task/ script periodically (every 5 min).

From your cron (or from within your script - it doesn't matter) you can call a java application with the `java -jar ${yourJarName}` command.

For this to work, you of course need to install and setup `Java` properly (install the *JRE* and maybe set some environment variables like `JAVA_HOME`).

When this is the case Java will be able to start successfully. To make it to start and run your application/ `JAR` successfully, your program needs to contain a valid **main method**. It' signature is `public static void main(args[])`. **Without such a method Java will not be able to run any application.**

Within the main method you can do anything you like - e.g. call your `fetchFromSFTP` method to perform the task.

In the above scenario the scheduling will be controlled by the *unix system cron scheduler*.

---

As you've used the `@Scheduled` annotation it might be the case you've created a `WAR` file and are executing it in a Servlet Container/ Application Container like *Tomcat*, *Wildfly* or *Websphere Liberty*.

This is also possible, but in this case you don't need to setup and use the *unix systems cron scheduler*. Since your `WAR` file will be executed in an Application Container which is running 24/7 by itself and the **Application Containers cron scheduler** will be used to execute your `fetchFromSFTP` method periodically.

I hope this is helpful and clears it up to you.

Comment: Thanks Sebsen, will implement your solution, appreciate it

Comment: Welcome, hope the answer can help you! When it's the case I'd appreciate it a lot when you also officially accept it as so :) Also if you have additional questions on this let me know in the comments. We can clarify it here or I can update the answer accordingly. Good luck and BR

Comment: Sounds good, but still some way to go. When you want to follow the main method approach, you wouldn’t need a tomcat. You can create a simple JAR file and call it with the „java -jar ..“ command. This will look for the main method and immediately execute it

Comment: Also do you really just to execute the curl? When it’s the case why don’t you run it directly from your Script? This will be mich simpler than executing it from Java. From Java you‘d usually an Http-Client library and rum your http requests with it. Can you maybe update your question and shot what you’re doing in your fetchfromSftp method?

Comment: Actually the requirement is automating the end point processing, previously, we used to start the tomcat server and hit the end point manually from the terminal on ec2, but now this end point needs to be automated and run automatically every 5 mins or whatever the time, so every 5 mins, it's gonna pick the file from ftp, insert into s3 and also hit the end point with the  same file name, will try executing it from the script, but the file name associated with the curl should be picked from ftp path, how can we configure the same in the script

Comment: Ok I think it is more clear now, but still there are a lot of open points (since it’s not 100% clear to me how your infrastructure looks like). But fetching from ftp can also be implemented pretty „easily“. There is the scp command you can copy files from remote systems with.

Comment: You mean issue a scp - i command to copy the latest file from the remote ftp and use the file name or variable in the curl statement in the crontab -e as all this is a part of the requirement.

Comment: Yes you can use the scp command to copy files from and to remote hosts (should also work with S3). How you can copy the latest file from a remote host you can find here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82459/how-to-download-the-latest-file-in-a-folder-using-a-scp. For more details to the scp command you can google for „man scp“. You cannot use the filename directly in crontab -e, but from the script called by it (start...mapper...sh)

Comment: Thanks Sebsen, I think we are getting closer to the solution, the steps would be: a. Copy the file from remote host to /home/ec2/ b. copy the same file to s3 from home/ec2 c.hit curl with the same filename : all the three statements need to be in  crontab -e, just digging more as to what exactly the three statements would be , if all the three statements are in crontab -e , will it work.

Comment: Yes, sounds like the way to go. Combining all this actions in one crontab entry will make the syntax quite complicated. So I‘d suggest you’ll write your own script which will be called by the crontab and the script will contain all the steps you’ve listed (like you’ve already started with your start...mapper...sh script). Looks like what you need to do is doable from shell and will be even simpler than from Java.

Comment: Yes Sebsan, that sounds good, will put everything in the script.

Comment: One challenge is scp command should pick up the latest file or file with the latest time stamp from the remote host folder, how to go about it

Comment: Yes I also thought so luckily there shall be a way to solve it (didn't test yet). As in my previous comment I've linked following post which should solve this issue: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82459/how-to-download-the-latest-file-in-a-folder-using-a-scp. Alternativey you can check this thread: https://www.unix.com/red-hat/113333-find-latest-file-dir-remote-machine-scp-local-machine.html

Comment: tried the following script: ssh -i ".pem file" ec2-user@remotehost
latest_file=$(ls -t | head -n 1)
echo $latest_file
scp - i ".pem file" ec2-user@remotehost:/path/filefolder/$latestfile
$ aws s3 sync filefolderins3 s3://bucketname/filefolderins3 --exclude *.tmp
upload: /home/ec2-user/$latest_file to s3://bucketfilename/filefoderins3/
curl -v http://localhost:8080/api/version/javafunctionname/$latest_file

Comment: And, did it work? At least looks like it's doing the right job. Also it s hard to read because of the formatting th "$ aws s3 sync ..." part is difficult to understand. Maybe you can update your question with the proper formatting of the script.

Comment: It's not working as the ssh with password option is not available and tried installing expect, sshpass and keychain , but it says not package avaialble., just need a proper bash script to read the latest file from a ftp remote host folder path and insert the same file to s3 bucket folder path.If this is resolved, then the automation process will work as per the cron job time.

Comment: Hi Sebsen, currently trying to execute the cron job from job launcher controller as below:

Comment: currently trying to execute the cron job from job launcher controller as below:   @GetMapping("/cv/{File}")      @Scheduled(cron="* */5 * * * *") public ResEntity updateCVins(@PathVariable("File") String completedVinFile) {
log.info("Processing File: {}" +  File
                String command = "curl -v http://localhost:8080/api/v1/cv/"+ File"
Trying to execute the end point from Job Launcher Controller, the tomcat server is starting all over every 5 mins, but the end point mentioned in the Job Launcher Controller is not getting executed. Let me know if you require any further info on this.

Comment: Hello Srikanth sorry have been occupied with other things at work recently. Nice to hear you made some progress and also could fix the keybased SSH login!
Regarding the NumberFormatException: You cannot pass null to the Integer.parseInt method - it'll lead to the error. What is "secrets" and where is it coming from? Looks like the key/ property "ftp-port" is not defined in it and therefore it's returning `null`.

Comment: The secrets is in the secret manager , the ftp-port is some integer , am trying to retrieve in the java class and parseInt method parameter is same as the parameter in aws secrets manager.

Comment: The numberformat exception is gone , had hard-coded for the port number for now, other error is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.

Comment: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: this error is not allowing me to connect to database, the connection attempt is failed, restarted the rds instance, and restarted the service , still same error.

Comment: Hi Sebsen, org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.any resolution you have got for this , when a curl is hit , it is not able to establish connection to database postgres, kinda stuck at this error in the automation task.

Comment: Hi Srikanth, sorry again took some time to reply. Regarding the secret you'll need to find out how to properly set it up, then the error will be gone. Hard-coding the value sounds like a temporary solution.
The connection exception can have many reasons. Is there maybe a firewall in between blocking the call (would result in a "Timeout")? Are you running in AWS, are the VPC set up properly? Are your credentials you use for the login correct? Is remote login for your user enabled in the DB? I think when you search for it on google, you'll also find a lot possible reasons and solutions for this

Comment: Thanks Sebsen for the detailed solutions, troubleshooted this issue and as you said had hard coded the secret  as well. the issue seems to be a firewall issue as you pointed out, our ops team is looking into it as they have the permissions.

Comment: Great! What I also remember is that each database vendor provides their own version of the driver - in case it shouldn't be the firewall issue and it won't help, consider downloading the latest and matching driver version from the vendors website (matching because it needs to match your Java and the vendors DB versions).
I hope it can resolve your issues and I'm glad I could help. When your issues are resolved I'd appreciate it a lot when you can also officially accept my answer as helpful/ correct. In case you have further issues or questions kindly let me know in the comments ofc

Comment: Yes Sebsen, sure, had tick marked one of your initial solutions which helped me to go ahead with the Cron Job scheduler.

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate a lot) Good luck with your matter and feel free to let me know in case you face further issues)

Comment: Hi Sebsen, all erros are debugged now, thanks for your timely solutions. one error on ec2 while am executing the jar fileis Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile x.jar, tried multiple solutions for this , but no fix yet

Comment: Hi Srikanth, great to hear! This is a tough one since it can have many reasons. First of all do you mean jar or war? Don’t you run it in your tomcat? Did you try to download the jar to your local is it also corrupt there? Good thing also is to open it with e.g 7-zip and check it’s contents. Alternatively you can simply extract it to get an overview. Also a good option is to run you build process (ant/ maven/ gravel?) locally and check the result. Maybe it’s an issue during scp copying which corrupts it. Maybe it’s wrong permissions on the directory/ jar itself (actually last I don’t believe)

Comment: the maven build is working fine without errors, but when it is copied onto ec2 using scp and executed on ec2, it's throwing this error, will download 7-zip and check it's contents. the jar file is maven build locally and then scp to the ec2

Comment: Depending on how you do the scp it might get corrupted. Probably there are some options to be set (e.g. transmit as file or as binary) to avoid it (at least I know it from WinSCP) - but other tools and the command line should provide the same options.

Comment: Thanks Sebsen for all the help and comments, the task is done now.

Comment: Great to hear, glad I could help! All the best to you and your projects :)

Comment: Thanks Sebsen, same to you as well, Can I still ineract with you here or do you have any linked in profile or email id, would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: One issue, how do we clear the date utc format string , am just checking for boolean value if (a= true){ m.tstamp=""} tried m.tstamp=="", m. timestamp==="", m. timestamp==='', m.tstamp=' '; which one would clear the timestamp, it is not throwing any error but it's not emptying the tstamp field in the api response.

Comment: Hi Sebsen, how to do an explicit commit on jdbc template from within the Java application. My update statement in Java application doesn’t throw any errors but it doesn’t update the database table column either

Comment: Hello Srikanth, currently I don't really have any further contact information - will think about that and let you know. Regarding the timestamp I'm not sure what you want to do. You want to modify the 'default', auto-generated timestamp by Spring? I think a good place for that is to look in the Spring Documentation and check how to achieve that. I can imagine there is a setting for that, or you need to clear the HTTP-Headers of the response for that. Regarding the last point: In Java EE (with Container Managed Transactions) you usually don't call commit yourself - actually it also is forbidden

Comment: and will lead to errors. The commit is automatically being done, once your request is processed. You also don't see your updates when your request is sucessfully processed?

Comment: Thanks Sebsen for the detailed analysis. here the scenario is database flags are not getting updated,but api response and logs show no errors.

Comment: Do you know how do we ssh into a docker image and check whether the repo files are actually changed or in sync with the bitbucket repo. Please advise if you know, Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a really strange situation.. are you sure the code is updating it as expected (-> no bug therein?), do you connect to the correct database to check? Did you try to manually change and commit it -> will it work or fail? Could you maybe debug the code with the same settings once on you local? This is the things I'd try to verify. SSHing to a docker should work like explained e.g. in this article: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-ssh-into-docker-container

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Sebsen. tried setAutoCommit(false) within the method.getting the jdbc connection exception

Comment: public void daoMethod(){

String query="Update tableA set flag='1' where id=? and id2=?";
jdbcTemplate().update(query,id,id2);
}The above method is getting executed without any errors and logs also show no errors, but the database column flag is not getting updated. Can anyone suggest a solution, tried to set auto commit false, @Transactional(readOnly=false), PlatformTransactionManager to commit , changed datatype in Database for flag to character, character varying, citext from text , but still not working.

Comment: Will the arguments in the where clause correctly be filled? Maybe the query and everything else is working completely fine, but no row will match the criteria and therefore 0 rows will be affected by the statement. Can you log the arguments and once execute it manually from a DBMS and see how it behaves?

Comment: There are rows which match the criteria and arguments in the where clause are correctly filled, no issues,one thing the uuid(id is of type uuid) is randomly generated in the java method and same uuid is in the where condition, this uuid value in the database and java application needs to be same , will check that. Thanks.

Comment: one issue : jdbctemplate.update() is updating only one row in the table instead of all rows, no errors or exceptions in the logs, can anyone assist, what is the solution, I can retrieve updaterowcount, but need to know why it's only updating only one row

Comment: Can you see and copy the executed query (activate some logging or copy it from the debugger)? Looks like your where Clauses written in a way only one row matches it's condition. On the other hand, maybe the additional rows which should also have been affected got inserted later, after the update has been run?

Comment: With the copied query, you can once execute it manually in a tool like the MySQL Workbench or SQLDeveloper and 'debug' it there and see how it's behaving

Comment: Thanks Sebsen for the inputs, your analysis is correct, there were some duplicate entries in the Database which are also getting retrieved which is causing the issue and throwing an incorrect resultset size exception

Comment: mutt "emaild" -s "subject.." is not going through on ec2 and is giving the below error in the logs:857DFB5FE7      699 Tue Apr 27 15:50:55  ec2-user@ip
(host y.com[x.x.x.x.] refused to talk to me: 554 Blocked - see https://ipcheck.proofpoint.com/?ip=x.x.x.x)@Sebsen, any clue on this issue, even our ops guy is not able to resolve it.